# Error starting Click-Once app. Application cannot be started. Contact the vendor

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, clickonce, full-trust

We are having a weird problem with on of our customer's clickonce installation. This is a full trust winforms application.

Our application installs correctly on the Windows 7 computer and the user can use it. After a day or a few hours of use, the application exe goes missing from the clickonce deployment directory along with a few DLLs as well.

The user can no longer run the application using the Desktop shortcut and he gets the "Error starting Click-Once app. Application cannot be started. Contact the vendor."

We tried uninstalling and reinstalling the application multiple times by clearing the Apps\2.0 clickonce cache. However, everytime we have the same issue.

We also tried creating a new user on the same machine and installing the software under the new user. However, the new user has the same problem as well.

We suspected virus activity. Unfortunately, the Virus guard does not mention any suspicious activity. A scan from another virus guard showed no threats.

Any clues as to what might be causing this behavior. The running exe just disappears from the install location.

The application runs fine elsewhere, on other computers.

Thank you,
Manish.

Comment: Turns out that this was a result of malfunctioning antivirus guard. The antivirus software was silently removing our files and not showing them in the report. On disabling the virus guard, software started functioning normally.